# CCNet vs Jenkins - one point configuration for multiple branches

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins, build-process, cruisecontrol.net

I recently heard a lot about jenkins, it's cool UI, easy to set up, so many plugins etc.. Currently I am using CCNet for CI. I thought of migrating to Jenkins looking at its cool features.

Soon i realized Jenkins lacks the most important feature - one point configuration - Define all the common configurations at one place and reuse them for multiple projects. Later I found there are couple of options available in Jenkins like copy from existing project or use Jenkins web API.

Problem with "Copy From existing project" is if i make any change in this project it won't be automatically reflected in all the projects copied from this.

There are environment variables but these are like global variables.

CCNet on contrary has very cool feature of "[Configuration Preprocessor](http://www.cruisecontrolnet.org/projects/ccnet/wiki/Configuration%20Preprocessor)" which is the core strength of ccnet i believe.

My conclusion is Jenkins is easy to setup and useful in case you have few projects.It becomes very difficult to maintain Jenkins as the number of projects increases.
CCNet is difficult to set up for the first time but once setup it requires minimal effort for any one to add a new project.

So my final thought was I won't be migrating to Jenkins.

Please share your thoughts on this and if people have faces similar issues when migrating? Also i would like to know if missed anything important in my analysis.

Comment: That's an accurate description, but unfortunately this is not a fit for SO.

Answer (score 1):

You should try the [Templates Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Template+Project+Plugin). The reviews aren't great, but it appears to be exactly what you're looking for.

Frankly, if you're happy with CC.net, I don't see a big reason to move. If you're unhappy, knowing more about what's missing might us steer you the right way.

Comment: I tried "Template Plugin" but they didn't serve my purpose. The idea is why do you want to show all the sections to the user  where he is just interested in changing the SCM address. Apparently i could just load the configuration from a central config file and override the needed values.
[job dsl plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Job+DSL+Plugin) is what i was interested in but it doesn't support Mercurial it seems.